# Buildfire: Getting datastore and userdata information from a different plugins

Tags: datastore, buildfire

I am trying to use buildfire.datastore and buildfire.userData.

Saving and using this info in one plugin.

Can I then reference that datastore and userData info in a different plugin?
If not, would the browsers localStorage work?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are not allowed to share data even among different instances of the same plugin. This is done for security reasons.

If your plugins share the same domain they can use the same local storage. However, if they do not share the same domain you can use the Shared LocalStorage in `buildfire.js`. See
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/LocalStorage

While BuildFire has on its roadmap a new database storage mechanism that will allow all plugins to share data. A good substitute for the would be using a service like Google's FireBase which works really well with BuildFire.

Hope this helps